# Error while interfacing my webcam to ROS

Tags: calibration, libuvc-camera, camera, cv-bridge, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed **ros-indigo-usb-cam** package and executed the code `rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node ~video_device "/dev/video0"` which resulted in following error

**[ERROR] [1435589390.503107344]: outbuf size mismatch.  pic_size: 604160 bufsize: 614400**

How to fix this error for my logitech USB webcam, also educate me how to view the vision specifications of the camera in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212462/error-while-interfacing-my-webcam-to-ros/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I meet the same problem. My camera is logitech C525. And I finally resolved it.

Go to the catkin workspace,

```
$ gedit src/usb_cam/src/usb_cam.cpp
```

find the sentence and comment it like this,

```
if (pic_size != avframe_camera_size_)
{
   //  ROS_ERROR("wocaonima, outbuf size mismatch.  pic_size: %d bufsize: %d", pic_size, avframe_camera_size_);
   //  return; 
}
```

Then,

```
$ catkin_make
```

So that, resolve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [ilekoaiq](https://answers.ros.org/users/24957/ilekoaiq/) with karma: 16 on 2015-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-11-22**:
If you believe that is the correct solution, please open a pull request so the maintainer knows about it: https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/usb_cam